# xpages rowData getDocument method

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

i did add the following code for one of my clickable ( show values in this column as links ):

```
if ( formName == "testForm1")

{ href + "/doc.xsp?documentId=" + docUNID + "&action=openDocument"; }

else if ( formName == "testForm2" )

{ // an opened pop-up with a message will be great! }
```

I read that you can use easily `window.alert`, but in Client Side. So, how can I refer to `rowData.getDocument().getItemValueString("Form")` using CS?

Or, it is possible to compute the `Show values in this column as links` property?

I did tried the `@WarningMessage('messageText')` formula but I need an other type of warning / message.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Sedar provided the solution, I just add a word of caution: getDocument() is expensive, so don't repeat, use a variable. Also recycle it after use. You probably would be better off to add Form as a column to your view (you don't need to display it), so you can avoid the getDocument() alltogether. And be careful with Popups: users routinely click them without reading - and they are alien to the web

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `view.postScript()` to send a CSJS code back to the client context.

```
view.postScript("alert('"+rowData.getDocument().getItemValueString("Form")+"')");
```

Comment: I was looking for something like this. Thank you.